# How to write VPC flow logs to an S3 bucket on another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I am trying to write VPC Flow logs (from account 1) to an S3 bucket (on account 2), using terraform:

```
resource "aws_flow_log" "security_logs" {
    log_destination      = "arn:aws:s3:::my_vpcflowlogs_bucket"
    log_destination_type = "s3"
    vpc_id               = var.vpc_id
    traffic_type         = "ALL"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "vpc_flow_logs" {
  name = "vpc_flow_logs"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "vpc-flow-logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "write_vpc_flow_logs" {
  name = "write_vpc_flow_logs"
  role = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_logs.id

  policy = jsonencode({
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogDelivery",
        "logs:DeleteLogDelivery"
        ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_vpcflowlogs_bucket"
    }
  ]
})
}
```

Account 1 & 2 belong to the same organisation.

I am getting the following response:

`Error creating Flow Log for (vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxx), error: Access Denied for LogDestination: my_vpcflowlogs_bucket. Please check LogDestination permission`

How can I make this work? This bucket contains sensitive information, therefore i have restricted every kind of public access.
I am guessing that there is a way to allow certain principals to write into the bucket even from different accounts, but I am unaware how.

[image]

## S3 Policy

```
{
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"},
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_vpcflowlogs_bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
                    "aws:SourceAccount": <account-1-id>
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs::<account-1-id>:*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"},
            "Action": ["s3:GetBucketAcl", "s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_vpcflowlogs_bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": <account-1-id>
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs::<account-1-id>:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What is your bucket policy? You need to allow `s3:PutObject` on `arn:aws:s3:::${Bucket}/AWSLogs/*` and `s3:GetBucketAcl` on `arn:aws:s3:::${Bucket}`. Also needs a service principal of `delivery.logs.amazonaws.com`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-s3.html

Comment: Did the modifications based on your (and docs) recommendations. I added the S3 bucket policy as well as the IAM role I assign to the VPC Flow Logs above. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you add the bucket encryption permissions? Check CloudTrail to find out exactly which permission is missing.

Comment: Just changed `aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs::<account-1-id>:*`to `aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:*:<account-1-id>:*` and it worked (added wildcard to the region part). Thank you Daniel.